# SQL Script to validate two databases

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've been tasked with writing a script to validate data that is being downloaded from one database (db1) to another (db2) during a nightly download by a 3rd party.

db1 is normalized while db2 is not. The data should be 1 to 1 and my company wants me to prove that because the information is critical and has to be correct.

I have never done this sort of thing and have never used Oracle before (MSSQL is what I normally use) so I wonder:

- What is the best approach/ best practices code wise/documentation
  wise?
- What should I be aware of using Oracle?

I would consider myself a little more advanced than Junior but I've only been doing SQL development for a few years. So anything else you might be able to think of would be a big help.

Comment: how will this job interact with the end user?  will it run out of a scheduler and send emails or post the validation results to some DB table or dump the results in some network dir or FTP?  do you know Perl? this looks like a perfect candidate for Perl

Comment: I don't know Pearl. The result of the script should show where the fields don't match, which will probably be dumped into an excel sheet.The end user of this job will be me and will probably be run a few times once the script is complete.

Comment: are these two tables on the same ORCL server?  if they are, looks like a simple outer join query

Comment: They are on the same server, but different databases. From my research so far, I will have to create a database link. As of now I lack the permissions but should receive them shortly.

Comment: so you need to write an outer join query to find if there are rows in table 1 that have not made their way into table 2.  are you familiar with outer joins?

Comment: How large is your data, in rows and bytes?  (The best method depends on the size of your data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation when migrating one database schema to another, and I posted this question on DBA Stack Exchange:

[Are there tools to perform data comparison between two different schemas?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/are-there-tools-to-perform-data-comparison-between-two-different-schemas)

I was using SQL Server but the mechanics of the solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then it could be as simple as creating a Database Link in Database-1 with details such as user id, password, TNS service name for Database-2 and use the DB Link as `@link_name` in queries in Database-1 to access Objects in Database-2.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) for more info.

Once you have a DB Link in place you can use queries like

```
select a.col1, b.col1
  from table1 a, 
       table1@dblink b   --this is a table in Database-2
 where a.col2 = b.col2
    ....
    ....;
```